# ng-show from controller Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller like this :

```
 $scope.checkCodeMeli = function (id) {

        var result = myHellperService.checkCodeMeli(id);
        if (result === false) {
            $scope.requesterViewModel.NationalCode = "";
            $scope.inValidMeliCode = "کد ملی نا معتبر می باشد";
        }
        else {
            $scope.GetRequesterByNationalCode(id);
        }

    }
```

and form like this :

```
<input ng-model="requesterViewModel.NationalCode" name="meli" type="text" placeholder="کد ملی" ng-blur="checkCodeMeli(requesterViewModel.NationalCode)" my-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true" required valid-number />
```

in controller i want to print out a message when checkCodeMeli function is false .
this ng-show doesn't work :
**ng-show :**

```
<span ng-show="checkCodeMeli.inValidMeliCode">{{inValidMeliCode}}</span>
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: seems like your trying to pass function to `ng-show`

    `..ng-show="checkCodeMeli(inValidMeliCode)"..`

Comment: not working,i'm trying to show message if function is false

Comment: ng-show works with true false value only. not false and msg....

Comment: Use ng-if in place of ng-show.. It will work..

Comment: something like this : <span ng-if="inValidMeliCode">{{inValidMeliCode}}</span> ?

Comment: ved that worked . thx
put this in answer section please

Comment: Ok.. I posted it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use `ng-if` in place of `ng-show.`. It will work..

Answer (score 0):

```
    $scope.checkCodeMeli = function (id) {

            var result = myHellperService.checkCodeMeli(id);
            if (result === false) {
                $scope.requesterViewModel.NationalCode = "";
                $scope.inValidMeliCode = "کد ملی نا معتبر می باشد";
    return false;
            }
            else {
                $scope.GetRequesterByNationalCode(id);
    return true;
            }

        }  

And Span is like :-

<span ng-show="checkCodeMeli(requesterViewModel.NationalCode)">{{inValidMeliCode}}</span>
```